# Gridview Column Header missing when export to csv in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, gridview

I am exporting a gridview to csv file. The code below works good, however the column header of gridview is missing in the csv file.

```
  Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.csv")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"

    Dim sBuilder As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()


    For index As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        sBuilder.Append(GridView1.Columns(index).HeaderText + ","c)
    Next

    sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)

    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For k As Integer = 0 To GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
            sBuilder.Append(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", "") + ",")
        Next
        sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next

    Response.Output.Write(sBuilder.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.[End]()
```

What should I do to include the column header to csv?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly the 'c' should not be at the end of the append when you are adding the column names and I would use the same method of itterating the columns headers e.g. either `GridView1.Columns.Count` or `GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count` but not both

Comment: So where should I put the 'c'?

Comment: What does the last  c in   sBuilder.Append(GridView1.Columns(index).HeaderText + ","c)   do? is it a string ? it's outside the quotation mark. Its a character? doesnt that violate .Append() parameters?

Comment: no it doesn't..i already tried removing that 'c' character but the result doesn't changes..

Comment: It shouldn't be there at all

Comment: Can you breakpoint through the routine and ensure it actually has data to load please? It may be that for some reason this routine is firing before the Gridview has loaded. Breakpointing will give us a lot of data to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem..I used below code to get the column header of gridview when exporting to csv.

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
        sBuilder.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text + ",")
 Next
```

Take note that this code works even the gridview property 'AutoGenerateColumns' is set to true..

Below is the complete code for exporting gridview to csv with Column header..

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.csv")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"

    Dim sBuilder As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
        sBuilder.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text + ",")
    Next

    sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)

    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For k As Integer = 0 To GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
            sBuilder.Append(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", "") + ",")
        Next
        sBuilder.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next

    Response.Output.Write(sBuilder.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.[End]()
```